# IBM MobileFirst v8.0 / Cordova / Windows 8.1 - Network error while running cordova app(windows 8.1 platform) through mobile first 8 in sync mode

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, windows-8.1, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have created a IBM MobileFirst platform v8.0 - cordova app for windows 8.1 using eclipse. Also, I have created a javascript adapter that just forwards my request to the actual server.

Adapter Code:

```
function callApi(request) {
        var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : '/path/path',
        body : {
            contentType : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            content : request.toString(),
        }
    };
    return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Adapter XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2016. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<mfp:adapter name="SAMPLE_Adapter"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:mfp="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
             xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>SAMPLE_Adapter</displayName>
    <description>SAMPLE_Adapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>192.168.something.something</domain>
            <port>9081</port>
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>300000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>300000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>500</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>


    <procedure name="callApi" secured="true" scope="appAuthenticity"/>




</mfp:adapter>
```

I have manually set the calls to server in SYNC mode by modifying this file: worklight.js

`xhr.open(method, finalUrl, false); // the last parameter is set to false which makes it SYNC. Defaut value is ASYNC (true)` .

The issue is when I clean my server and register my adapter and app and run, the calls are working. But after a while or after a system restart when I run the app again, I get a 'Network Error' on the following line in worklight.js:

```
 xhr.send(method === 'GET' ? null : contentString, true);
```

Also, I get the same error when I run the app in some other device by side loading it. It doesn't even run a few times like it does on the machine I register it from.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: "I have manually set the calls to server in SYNC mode" - why? You should not be changing MFP SDK. This is not supported or recommended. 
If you face issues after modifying the SDK , you should revert the changes and then try out

Comment: Then how do you suggest that I make my calls SYNC ?

Comment: Why do you want to set your calls to Sync? What do you gain by it? Also , why is your adapter procedure protected by appauthenticity and not some custom scope? This is on purpose